# Calculate optimal speed/cadence/heart rate

Tags: python, r, analytics, data-analysis, gpx

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I want to calculate what the 'most optimal' cadence/speed combination is where my heart rate is low. I know that there are a lot of other variables that will (negatively) influence this, but I need to start somewhere :)

Over a period of time I generated a few GPX files with the following content (per second):

- heartrate
- speed
- cadance

> ```
> For example, see this table:
> | speed    | heartrate | cadance |
> |----------|-----------|---------|
> | 4:55 /km | 139 bpm   | 170 spm |
> | 4:55 /km | 155 bpm   | 170 spm |
> | 4:53 /km | 156 bpm   | 176 spm |
> | 4:57 /km | 158 bpm   | 176 spm |
> | 4:54 /km | 160 bpm   | 174 spm |
> | 4:53 /km | 163 bpm   | 174 spm |
> | 4:47 /km | 165 bpm   | 176 spm |
> ```

What is the *best* way to calculate the lowest heartrate for the *best* combination of heart rate and speed? I can do this by grouping these two columns and then sorting from the lowest heart rate. However, that doesn't mean it is the *fastest* speed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This community is generally more concerned about issues regarding _code_ than _how do I XYZ.._. However, a multiple regression sounds like a possible starting point for your question. Try rephrasing your question and show your attempt with any eventual errors or subsequent questions.

Comment: @Dave load data into pandas df, then filter on low heart rate and sort by speed/cadence